Angular 14 | app-root empty | Deploy on vercel
I deployed my Angular project to Vercel and everything seemed successful, "no errors reported". However, none of the components are loading. As I'm new to Angular, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Does anyone have any experience with this?
I've tried troubleshooting the deployment issue by modifying the vercel.json (specifying the deploy command), adding resources and scripts to angular.json, and even creating a redirect file to index.html in dist folder. Unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the problem with the components not loading.browser html body browser console angular.json vercel.json app.routing.ts app-routing.module.ts structure of project
